# Assign two domain names to a single EC2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, domain-name, domain

I am running an AWS EC2 Linux instance with Elastic IP `a.b.c.d.` and I am hosting two different websites on it:

- ServiceA: http://a.b.c.d/serviceA
- ServiceB: http://a.b.c.d/serviceB

I have purchased the following domains: `serviceA.com` and `serviceB.com` and I would like to assign them to the proper hosting path. I found how to do it with URL redirect. Is there a way to do it through DNS configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Make both domains point to your IP (A records).

On the AWS EC2 Linux web server configuration, set `serviceA.com` and `serviceB.com` as [Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) for serviceA and serviceB folders respectively. The server will show one website or the other based on which `Host:` header it receives.